# Visa requirements for cruising in Vietnam for a UK citizen

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, vietnam, cruising

A cruise I am taking is stopping at two ports in Vietnam for a day each time.  Will I need a visa? Or do the cruise companies organise them?

Comment: You'd probably get a more definitive answer if you asked the cruise company directly...

Answer (score 1):

Vietnam Visa fee for cruise passengers back to US$5 per pax
http://vietnamvisaembassy.org/vietnam-visa-fee-cruise-passengers-back-us5-per-pax/

but better call you travel agencty, customer service and there ask, they probably have best answer...